# Create executable for Windows from python codebase that needs poppler

Tags: python, pyinstaller, poppler

I am using [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) in my code that in turn needs PATH to have the `/bin` folder of the Poppler binaries. I will need this in the PATH even after I create an executable that can run on Windows. Pyinstaller is great but [does not support](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) poppler yet. How do I go about packaging this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pyinstaller --add-binary 'path\to\poppelr' script_name.py`

The `--add-binary` flag points `pyinstaller` to the binary location so it can include it.

**edit 2**

Use the `os` module to add to `SYSTEM PATH`.

I am using `Jitsi.exe` as a proof of concept. This is a program I have that is not on system path. replace it with the path to the program you want to run.

```py
import os

# The os.eviron method returns a dict object of the users PATH
path = os.environ['PATH']
path = path + ';C:\Program Files\Jitsi' # Append the path to bin as a string
os.environ['PATH'] = path # Override value of 'PATH' key in the dict
print(os.environ['PATH']) # This is the new updated PATH
os.system('Jitsi') # Using system shell to call a program that was not on my PATH and now is
```

**Note:**
This updates the path **for the current process only**. Once the python process ends the PATH is returned to it's previous state.

Tested on a windows system

Comment: Thank you, but will `--add-binary` update the system PATH?

Comment: @user2775878 I changed my answer as the old one didn't update system PATH. Please see if this helps you and update me